# select people that with column value 1 and not 4

Tags: mysql

the question is to:

List the names of patrons who have purchased tickets in performance id 1 but not 4.

relevant table
1) performance

```
SaleId > SaleTime > Total > PerformanceId > PatronId
1   2014-02-12 12:10:11 100.00  1   1
2   2014-02-12 12:10:11 40.00   1   2
3   2014-02-12 12:10:11 30.00   1   3
4   2014-02-12 12:10:11 30.00   1   null
5   2014-02-12 12:10:11 100.00  4   1
6   2014-02-12 12:10:11 40.00   4   5
7   2014-02-12 12:10:11 30.00   4   3
8   2014-02-12 12:10:11 30.00   4   null
9   2014-02-12 12:10:11 100.00  7   1
10  2014-02-12 12:10:11 40.00   7   4
11  2014-02-12 12:10:11 30.00   7   3
12  2014-02-12 12:10:11 30.00   7   null
```

2) Patron

```
PatronId > lastName > firstName

1   Paul      Smith
2   Linda     Odom
3   Gigi      Koo
4   Kailee    Jefferson
5   Kimberly  Heart
6   boyle     Heart
7   Kimberly  Beetle
8   boyle     Beetle
9   Joe       Junior
10  Jane      Junior
11  Junior    Junior
12  Kar       Kargoolie
```

my SQL code is :

```
select distinct lastName, firstName
from Patron p, ticketsale t1, ticketsale t2
where p.PatronId = t1.PatronId
and p.PatronId = t2.PatronId
and t1.PerformanceId = 1
and t2.PerformanceId <> 4;
```

This does not work as it provides 3 names (paul, linda, gigi) and I should only be getting (Linda)

Comment: where is the table ticketsale ... is performance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Query**

Using subqueries with [`EXISTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) and the contrary (not exists):

```
SELECT
  pt.lastname, pt.firstname
FROM
  patron pt
WHERE
  EXISTS ( 
           SELECT 1 
           FROM performance pf 
           WHERE pt.patronid = pf.patronid AND pf.performanceid = 1 
         )
  AND NOT EXISTS ( 
           SELECT 1 
           FROM performance pf 
           WHERE pt.patronid = pf.patronid AND pf.performanceid = 4 
         )
```

---

**Testing**

See the live example on [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4e92/4)

I'm using only patrons that are in your sample data in table performance (others are not needed to prove the point):

```
create table patron(patronid int, lastname varchar(50), firstname varchar(50));
insert into patron values 
(1, 'Paul', 'Smith'),
(2, 'Linda', 'Odom'),
(3, 'Gigi', 'Koo'),
(4, 'Kailee', 'Jefferson'),
(5, 'Kimberly', 'Heart');

create table performance(performanceid int, patronid int);
insert into performance values
(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,null),(4,1),(4,5),(4,3),(4,null),(7,1),(7,4),(7,3),(7,null);
```

My query returns:

```
lastname | firstname
---------+----------
Linda    | Odom
```

Comment: I tried yours and I get an error code: unknown column 'pf.patronid' in 'where clause'.. I am not sure how to address this, but I added performance pf in the global FROM clause and it did nothing.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I had a typo, but other than that all should be fine.

Comment: thanks for redoing it, but for some reason the error is always the same. I am not sure why your statements wont work on mysql workbench 6.3 CE

Comment: Seems like you have an error because of the name of column `patronid` in `performance` table. It doesn't exist. Are you sure the naming is correct? Maybe it has been created with backticks like \`patronid\` ?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
SELECT firstName,
  lastName
FROM patron pat
INNER JOIN performance per1
  ON pat.PatronID = per1.PatronID AND per1.PerformanceID = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN performance per2
  ON pat.PatronID = per2.PatronID AND per2.PerformanceID = 4
WHERE per2.PerformanceID IS NULL
```

Just tried it on `ConsiderMe` sqlfiddle. You can change the condition on the `per2.PerformanceID` to a different ID if you want to check for, say, persons who bought tickets from ID 1 but not on 7, and so on.

If you want to understand whats happening select `per1.PerformanceID` and `per2.PerformanceID` as well on the query then check the table output and then you'll understand that:

- You can join multiple times the same table, under different criteria (and avoid subqueries which are less performant)
- Use the where, with different aliases of the same table to filter the data

Comment: You mean you've tried it on __my__ sqlfiddle, right ? :P

Comment: @ConsiderMe LOL, I should totally CONSIDER you haha, sorry about that, but you are right it was your fiddle... that is what happens when you just reply rushed

Comment: Haha, that was a joke, no need to mention me in the post. But yeah ;-) Leaving +1

Comment: lmao! I am not sure why, but yours is giving me an error : Unknown column per1.PatronID in 'on clause'

Comment: @tcmike weird... it works fine on the sqlfiddle... what version of mysql do you have?

Comment: it seems to be causing these sort of issues on yours and cosiderme's statements. I am not sure what is causing this, but i am using mysql workbench 6.3 CE.

Comment: @tcmike Workbench is just the version of the tool you are using, what matters is the version of the mysql/mariadb engine

Answer (score 1):

I think you simple should do a where condition  on a single table

```
 select distinct p.lastName, p.firstName
 from Patron p
 inner join ticketsale as t2 (on p.PatronId = t2.PatronId and t2.PerformanceId = 1)
 where p.PatronId not in  (select distinct t1.PatronId 
 from ticketsale as t1  where t1.PerformanceId <> 4)
```

Comment: that does clean up the code. thanks for that. However, this doesn't solve my problem because I am still getting 3 names back instead of the 1.

Comment: But yuo have 3 patron with performanceID = 1 so how you think you shoudl obtain only one name .. you have only on patron who see the performance 4 ... if you explain better then i can search for the right solution ..

Comment: I am searching for someone who HAS bought performanceID = 1  AND HASNT bought performanceID=4 (only PatronID = 2.. which is Linda Odom)

patronID 1 and 3 are in both ID 1 and 4
patronID 2 is only in ID 1 (the answer)

Comment: also t2.performanceId = 4  doesnt work because your answer has no use for t2

Comment: error code: 1064. You have an error in syntax: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'left join ticketsale t1 on p.patronId = t1.PatronId'

Comment: This is giving me 3 names still. (paul, linda, gigi) . Thanks for helping